# Long delay when calling a WCF-service from silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a silverlight 3 application, that fetches some simple data from a ms-sql-server 2008 via WCF. At first, it gets all ids (~2000) that are stored in the database and then subsequently fetches all the details of those ids from another table (~10 records per id on average).

My problem is, that it takes very long from calling the details to actually getting the results (~ 13-18 seconds). After the first details-item is fetched, the rest comes in quickly.

Where shall I look for the bottle neck?

Here's the code I use. At first, my two WCF-methods

This one gets the ids

```
    public HashSet<int> GetAllIds()
    {
        HashSet<int> resultSet = new HashSet<int>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id FROM stammDaten", connection);

            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    resultSet.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.instance.ErrorRoutine(e, "");
        }

        connection.Close();

        return resultSet;
    }
```

This one gets the details for the single ids:

```
    public List<GeoKoordinates> GetGeoKoordinatesById(int stammDatenId)
    {
        List<GeoKoordinates> resultSet = new List<GeoKoordinates>();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT stammDatenId, position, latitude, longitude FROM geoKoordinates WHERE stammDatenId=@stammDatenId ORDER BY stammDatenId, position", connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stammDatenId", SqlDbType.Int));
            command.Parameters["@stammDatenId"].Value = stammDatenId;

            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    GeoKoordinates geoKoors = new GeoKoordinates();
                    geoKoors.stammDatenId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    geoKoors.position = reader.GetInt32(1);
                    geoKoors.latitude = reader.GetDouble(2);
                    geoKoors.longitude = reader.GetDouble(3);

                    resultSet.Add(geoKoors);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.instance.ErrorRoutine(e, "");
        }

        connection.Close();

        return resultSet;
    }
```

And here are the functions of my silverlight-app, that consume those methods. _s1 is an instance of the ServiceReference to my WCF-app

```
private void InitMap()
{
            ...
        _s1.GetAllIdsCompleted += new System.EventHandler<OSMDeepEarthExample.ServiceReference1.GetAllIdsCompletedEventArgs>(s1_GetAllIdsCompleted);
    _s1.GetGeoKoordinatesByIdCompleted += new System.EventHandler<GetGeoKoordinatesByIdCompletedEventArgs>(s1_GetGeoKoordinatesByIdCompleted);
    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    _s1.GetAllIdsAsync();
    }
```

This one is called, when the wcf-service returns the ids

```
    void s1_GetAllIdsCompleted(object sender, OSMDeepEarthExample.ServiceReference1.GetAllIdsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlockTest.Text += (DateTime.Now - _startTime).Seconds.ToString();

    foreach (int id in e.Result)
    {
        _s1.GetGeoKoordinatesByIdAsync(id);
    }
}
```

And finally, the one that handles the returned detail-sets.

```
    void s1_GetGeoKoordinatesByIdCompleted(object sender, GetGeoKoordinatesByIdCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlockTest.Text += (DateTime.Now - _startTime).Seconds.ToString();

    if (e.Result.Count > 0)
    {
        Polygon thePoly = new Polygon();
        _myLayer.Add(thePoly);

        ObservableCollection<Point> myPoints = new ObservableCollection<Point>();

        foreach (GeoKoordinates ko in e.Result)
        {
            Point point = new Point(ko.longitude, ko.latitude);

            if (!myPoints.Contains(point))
                myPoints.Add(point);
        }

        thePoly.Points = myPoints;
                    ... more polygone formatting ...

    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what you're doing:

```
Call WCF
Open db connection
get 2000 records
close connection

for 1 to 2000
    Call WCF
    open db connection
    get 10 records
    close connection
next
```

20 seconds seems very fast to make 2001 calls to WCF and opening and closing the database connection 2001 times.

try it like this:

```
Call WCF once
Open db connection
get 2000 records
for 1 to 2000
    get 10 records
next
close db connection

return a List<GeoKoordinates>
```

1 WCF call and 1 database connection should be much faster

Comment: Yap, that's the problem. I solved it by calling the WCF 1 time with a list of 2000 ids, instead of calling it 2000 times with just one id. In the stored procedure, that returns the records, I write this list into a temporary table. Then I join this temp table with the table that contains the data I want to fetch. So I get all the data I need at once.